# Convergence of random variable in $L^1$

Tags: probability-theory

I have following question:
Assume that $EX_n\rightarrow a$, for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$, with $n\rightarrow\infty$. What does it mean? Does the sequence $X_n$ convergence to a in $L^1$ i.e. $E|X_n-a|\rightarrow 0$? I guess it is true or maybe we need additional assumption...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $EX_n\to a$ means that
$$
|EX_n-a|=|E(X_n-a)|\to 0
$$
as $n\to \infty$ (i.e. the sequence of numbers  $(EX_n)$ converges to $a$). If $X_n\to a$ in $L^1$ then the triangle inequality implies that $EX_n\to a$. Indeed,
$$
|E(X_n-a)|\leq E|X_n-a|
$$
but the converse is not true. Indeed let $X_n$ be $2^n$ with probability $1/2$ and $-2^{n}$ with probability $1/2$. So $EX_n=0$ for all $n$ but $E|X_n|=2^n\to \infty$.